# Trying to add a line to my bashrc but it's not working

Tags: sed

I am trying to add a line after I find some text to my .bashrc but I don't have my syntax correct.

Can someone help me.

I want to add the line   "alias cls='clear'  after the egrep line in the .bashrc file.

Here is what I have so far.

sed ':\egrep:a alias cls='clear' .bashrc

Thanks
RC

Comment: I cn't tell exactly what you're doing from your example, so I'll offer [this article](https://fabianlee.org/2018/10/28/linux-using-sed-to-insert-lines-before-or-after-a-match/).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to add stuff to your `.bashrc` with `sed`?

Answer (score 3):

I can spot two issues:

1. if you want to use `:` as a regex delimiter in the address expression, you need to escape the `:` itself not the following `e` character
2. you have an unbalanced single quote

So either

```
sed "\:egrep:a alias cls='clear'" .bashrc
```

or simply

```
sed '\:egrep:a alias cls=clear' .bashrc
```

since you don't really need to quote `clear` here (if you ever **do** need to embed a single quote in a single-quoted expression, close the quote and then reopen it i.e. `'\''`).

To apply the changes to the file in-place, add the `-i` command line option.

Comment: Why not add it to .bash_aliases? 
@r-c-man

Comment: Thank you. I actually didn't know about .bash_aliases.  

I do now :)

I'm looking up Bash Startup files and it doesn't show that. It shows .bash_profile, .bash_login and .profile  I guess it's different depending on where you look.

Comment: @r-c-man the `~/.bash_aliases` file isn't mentioned in the bash manual's section on shell invocation because it's not an intrinsic startup file; it's just sourced by the default Debian/Ubuntu `~/.bashrc` if it exists